# Adding variable names to lists

Tags: python, bokeh

So, I'm dynamically creating a bokeh plot and need to create a tuple like this

```
('Matbock', [Matbockl, Matbockc])
```

The items in the list portion need to be variable names (no quotes) I'm currently able to create the tuple as all strings, `('Matbock', ['Matbockl', 'Matbockc'])`   but that doesn't work within the Bokeh legend code. I am dynamically creating elements for the chart and I need to reference those lines and circles (Matbockl and Matbockc) within the legend list of tuples and I'm at a bit of an impass as to how to do that.

Basically, the Bokeh part of it isn't important, just the ability to create a tuple with variable names instead of strings is what I'm after. These then get ammended into a list of tuples for use within the legend declaration of Bokeh.

```
[('Matbock', [Matbockl, Matbockc]), ('Atlas', [Atlasl, Atlasc])]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

To clarify further, or perhaps to simplify the question, the instantiation of 'Matbockl' and 'Matbockc' aren't the issue. I have done it both as dictionary references and as dynamic variables (yes I know, but I was trying to figure out how to get the name passed) and the problem always comes back to how to pass the information into the Bokeh legend.

At the end of the day, I am trying to pass my chart items into this...

```
legend = Legend(items=[
    ("iLitter",   [ll1, lc1]),
    ("Zagnut the destroyer",   [ll1, lc1]),
    ("Woot",   [ll1, lc1])
], location=(5, -40))
```

I am attempting to build the 'item' list you see above. I couldn't figure out how to build that items list as it is displayed above. Nothing I tried would get me this exact construct. Most commonly I'd have quotes around my variable references "Il1", which cause the chart to fail.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you want the objects pointed to by `Matbockl` and `Matbockc` in the tuple? Are you trying to dynamically get a string that represents the variable name? Some more information about what you are doing with Bokeh may help others know how to help.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.... 

Within the legend of the Bokeh plot it wants a list. I am building that list, along with the individual chart objects. The final list has to be in the form of

items = [('Matbock', [Matbockl, Matbockc]), ('Atlas', [Atlasl, Atlasc])]

So I am creating the list of tuples to accomplish this, but as I do the variable references are being inserted as strings, like the following..

('Matbock', ['Matbockl', 'Matbockc'])

I'm simply trying to get the two items in the tuple to be variables (no quotes) instead of strings.

I hope that helped

Comment: Please update your question with a small snippet of your code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that shows the initialization of the `Matbockl` and `Matbockc` variables as well as where you pass them to Bokeh. I can't think of a way that variables are getting replaced by their identifiers unless the variables are strings that contain their string identifier.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question you're trying to make a list and fill it with tuples dynamically with functions.

here's an example

```
a = 'name'
b = ['my', 'list']
tuple([a,tuple(b)])
>>> ('name', ('my', 'list'))
```

or if you specifically want a list in the tuple

```
tuple([a, b])
>>> ('name', ['my', 'list'])
```